# Why Mathieu group M11 is sharply 4-transitive?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am studying Steiner system and Construction of Mathieu groups from automorphism of some Steiner system.Mathieu group M11 is automorhism group of S(4,5,11) Steiner system. I am not able to understand why Mathieu group M11 is sharply 4-transitive?I know what is mean by sharply 4-transitive.But I am not getting any idea how to prove it.
In general is there any procedure to show transitivity of some Group?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There is an elementary proof given in Chapter $9$ "Permutations and the Mathieu Groups" of Rotman's book "An introduction to the theory of groups". 
The proof works inductively. It starts with showing that $M_{10}$ acts sharply $3$-transitively on $X=GF(9)\cup \{ \infty\}$. Then a transitive extension of $M_{10}$ acting on $\widetilde{X}=\{X,\omega\}$ is constructed, where $\omega$ is a new symbol. It is shown that there is an $h$ such that $M_{11}:=\langle M_{10},h \rangle$ acts sharply $4$-transitively on $\widetilde{X}$.
The result is:

**Theorem:** There exists a sharply $4$-transitive group $M_{11}$ of degree $11$ and order $7920$ such that the stabilizer of a point is $M_{10}$.

By direct counting arguments one can see that this $M_{11}$ is the usual Mathieu group of order $7920$.
For details see Theorem $9.52$ in this [handout on Mathieu groups](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEUQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.umn.edu%2F~webb%2Foldteaching%2FYear2010-11%2FMathieuHandout.pdf&ei=QK0yVKTzGsmwPLqigeAB&usg=AFQjCNEGqa3yHI-c7voNpkdPE-NWzsSnGg&bvm=bv.76802529,d.ZWU).
Of course, the choices in this construction can be better understood if one sees the relation between Steiner systems and Mathieu groups.

Edit: To reduce $k$-transitivity to $(k-1)$-transitivity, one can use the following lemma:

**Lemma:** Suppose that $G$ is transitive on $X$. Then $G$ is $k$-transitively on $X$ if and only if $Stab_G(x)$ acts $(k-1)$-transitive on $X\setminus \{x \}$.